# Error in executing windows service file

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am trying to execute windows service using following command 
C:\Windows\system32>installutil.exe MyNewService.exe

but i am getting below error:
Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Win
dows\system32\MyNewService.exe' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot fi
nd the file specified..

I tried various blogs saying some problem with spaces and all but i cant find suitable modifications to my code.
Anybody can tell me which modifications i required?

Comment: Is your service located in that folder?

Comment: is c:\windows\system32\ the location of MyNewService.exe?

Comment: No my application location is G:\MyProjects\MyNewService\MyNewService

Comment: but when i run command prompt from visual studio as an administrator and changes the path also it shows like that only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is because your "installutil.exe" is not located in the "C:\Windows\system32"
This is a .NET framework file and will be found under the version of .NET framework. For example for Framework 4.0 you can find this file here: "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"

I will recommend opening a command prompt window and 'cd' into "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319', then execute the following command.

> > installutil.exe G:\MyProjects\MyNewService\MyNewService.exe

This should fix your issue.

Comment: Hi there, I have tried your solution. First start up the cmd as Administrator, then navigate to the location of "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319", follow with command installutrl "H:\Exconmiser\ShipdataLogger.exe"; I am still getting the error (Exception occurred while initializing the installation : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly or one of it dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..) I think the possible reason behind this is the H drive is my computer network shared drive.

Comment: Yes, I put the Windows Service executable in C:\ drive and run the same script, it worked. The Commit phase completed successfully. The transacted install has completed.

Answer (score 3):

It may be a permissions issue for the `System32` folder. Try moving your service executable (and other related files) out to something like `C:\MyNewService\` and call the install like this `C:\Windows\system32>installutil.exe C:\MyNewService\MyNewService.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that is a very generic error that could have many issues behind it. Basically the .NET runtime was unable to fully load the file, this could mean there is a problem with the file itself in odd cases, or most likely one of its dependencies could not be located.

Note that dependencies often chain, so an assembly that you reference could reference another assembly that is missing. A couple of recommendations:

- Double check whether any of your dependencies are not strong signed.
- If they aren't strong signed they should be in the same directory as your service.
- If they are strong signed they should either be in the GAC (make sure it is the right one, putting a .NET 4 DLL in the .NET 2 GAC won't work) or in the same directory.
- If the dependency is in the GAC, try putting a copy in the local directory to avoid any problems.
- Finally if you are still having issues, look into debugging dependencies, specifically the [Fusion Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), note that there are many ways to get to that date, I just linked to the first result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your concern 
I got the solution .
Actually I was giving installutil MyNewService.exe

instead i have to give
installutil MyNewService.exe fullpath....